# Mixing implicit and explicit CUDA streams

Tags: c++, cuda

I have some CUDA 8.0 code (edit: that I inherited, not something I wrote) that looks basically like this:

```
cudaMemcpy(devInputData, ..., cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
kernelThings<<<GRIDS, BLOCKS, 0, myStream>>>(devInputData);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

`cudaMemcpy()` works synchronously without a stream, so this code is correct, as far as I understand.

If I compile using [`CUDA_API_PER_THREAD_DEFAULT_STREAM`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/stream-sync-behavior.html), is this code still safe? I argue no, the `cudaMemcpy()` now happens asynchronously, so there is a potential for the kernel to start before `cudaMemcpy()` finishes. However, looking at the `Nsight` profiler, I see there is no overlap - textually I saw:

```
[Memcpy HtoD]
                  [kernelThings]
```

With a 16 microsecond gap between the two functions. This behaviour was repeated multiple times within the application.

However, I next deleted `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`, reran `Nsight`, and saw that now they overlapped:

```
[Memcpy HtoD]
         [kernelThings]
```

The kernel now started 10 microseconds before the `cudaMemcpy` finished.

Obviously, the correct fix is to use a stream with `cudaMemcpyAsync()` too:

```
cudaMemcpyAsync(devInputData, ..., cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, myStream);
```

However, my question is why did I not see the processes overlap when using `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`? Is the simple answer that I might not be so lucky with a different version of CUDA or GPU?

Comment: "cudaMemcpy() works synchronously without a stream, so this code is correct, as far as I understand." <- But note that something else might theoretically write to that buffer between the `cudaMemcpy()` and the execution of the kernel.

Comment: I don't think this can be explained in terms of user code. The `cudaMemcpy` call is blocking except for extremely small transfer sizes. Unless you are hitting that corner case, there is theoretically no way the kernel launch can preempt the memory copy *in host execution order*.  The fact the streams are different should not matter. My guess would be that you are seeing driver side scheduling effects here. If the driver batches commands (the modern WDDM driver definitely does, others might) then it is definitely possible the user code implicit synchronous behaviour could change.

Comment: I doubt this question can be authoritatively answered without a [mcve], and I would recommend including additional details such as the platform and GPU type, compute mode, and compile command.  For example, if this is happening multiple times in the application, perhaps you are seeing overlap with a kernel issued *prior* to the `cudaMemcpy` call.  Removing the `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` would be consistent with that theory.

Answer (score -1):

Don't rely on the crutches of implicit/default streams and ops and their synchronization behavior. For your first, "Hello world" level programs - that may be convenient, but as you yourself are noticing, you have to become an API lawyer or a psychic to guess what exactly will happen in certain complex scenarios.

Just make sure that each buffer you are using in your kernel is either:

1. Populated by a previous action on the same command queue or
2. 2.1 If it's an input buffer - has an event-pair ensuring anything affecting the buffer occur before kernel launch on the other stream, and

   2.2 If it's an output buffer - has an event-pair ensuring the kernel is executed before the output buffer is used elsewhere

Comment: I should have mentioned that this code is inherited code, not stuff I wrote myself, so that's I'm trying to understand why it (sort-of) works.

Comment: I fail to see how this actually answers the question asked

Comment: @talonmies: It suggests an approach to "mixing implicit and explicit CUDA schemes", which avoids the uncertainty OP is facing.

Comment: "my question is why did I not see the processes overlap when using cudaDeviceSynchronize()?"